# Find the minimum and maximum values for variables from two equations

Tags: proof-verification, systems-of-equations

I'm looking at a problem where the following two equations are given:
$$
xy \ge C
$$
and 
$$
a \le {\frac{x}{y}} \le b,
$$
where $x> 0, y >0$.

Then they say at which values min/max values for $x$ and $y$ will be got, namely:
$$x_{min}=\sqrt {Ca}, x_{max}=\sqrt {Cb}, y_{min}=\sqrt {{\frac{C}{b}}}, y_{max}=\sqrt {{\frac{C}{a}}}$$

I'm trying to understand how this is implied from the two equations.
So, from he first equation one can say that $x\ge {\frac{C}{y}}$. By plugging that in the second equation we get $a \le {\frac{C}{y^2}} \le b$. Here, I'm not sure that all equations should be kept as in the original equation. If being able to keep it, I'd get $ay^2\le C$, from where I'd derive min and max values for $y$.

So can someone explain how exactly to derive the four variables?

Comment: Do x and y have to be positive?

Comment: yes, forgot to mention that.